# Calling popViewControllerAnimated from an UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have created a button in a `UIView` subclass . I need to call `popViewControllerAnimated` via this button , but nothing work ! and I cannot see the viewController push back to rootViewController . here is my code :

```
- (void)SomeFunction {

 backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [backButton showsTouchWhenHighlighted];

        [backButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(backToMainMenu)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (void)backToMainMenu {

    [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSLog(@"back");
}
```

I change the code to this :

```
UINavigationController *vc = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController;
    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but nothing happens .

Comment: Please don't try to access controllers this way. It brakes all the design pattern of MVC. A view never has to know about the controllers architecture. Put your button's code in a controller.

Comment: Even I try to fire a method from viewController still nothing happens  `ContentViewController*vc;
    [vc backToMainMenu];`  @ryancrunchi

Comment: why dont you use simple for popviewcontroller,  [self.nagigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @virus I have told this method is inside a custom class which is subclass of `UIView`

Comment: is there logged any error in console if than that can be help to figure out issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the proper target format which takes the button as an argument. So add target function like this:

```
[backButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(backToMainMenu:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and the target should look like this:

```
- (void) backToMainMenu:(UIButton *) sender{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Still nothing ! it's strange I had same problem before but this it doesn't work ! !! !

Comment: Dumb question but have to ask: I take it this view controller with the button was pushed on rather than being modal and the backToMainMenu method is called?

Comment: Also what is your view hierarchy? Anything in there like you pushing a nagivation controller, root is a split view controllers etc...

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to use *Delegate* pattern because in your current logic you are breaking the MVC architecture and guidelines.

Create a `Protocol` in your subview class. The receiver of this delegate would be the view controller class from which you are showing your view. In event handling of the button, call the delegate method and from the view controller you would be able to call `popViewControllerAnimated` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your fundamental problem (besides design) is in (void)backToMainMenu ... self.window.rootViewController.navigationController will be nil, so this method does nothing

from UIViewController class reference:
*If the receiver or one of its ancestors is a child of a navigation controller, this property contains the owning navigation controller. This property is nil if the view controller is not embedded inside a navigation controller.*

so you see, the rootViewController cannot be embedded inside a nav controller can it, it is the bottommost one..

why don't you test this:

```
{
    UINavigationController *vc = self.window.rootViewController.navigationController;

    if (vc==nil){
    NSLog(@"nav controller is nil, this will never work");
    }

    [vc.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I also fully agree with @rory's answer there about design..

PS did you actually create a UINavigationController in order to push this viewController?